# Any 'design pattern' of c++ enable_if and SFINAE?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I did quite some searches on Internet and I found some examples of enable_if in different contexts.

However, pretty much all of the examples I found are 'dummy' examples, which can be done easily through inheritance and other OO approaches.

I am wondering what's the real world application of enable_if, the one that is difficult to be implemented in OO.

Or in other words, in what kind of application enable_if could be most useful/elegant?

Can anyone provide an example here?

I can understand c++ std library uses a lot of enable_if, but I have no intension to write a std library.

I am currently working on fleet management software. I am wondering if there is any kind of 'pattern' for using enable_if in software design.

For example, enable_if can be used to 'differentiate' return type:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value> f(T t){
    //integral version
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value> f(T t){
    //floating point version
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) comes to mind. Your question is too broad though, have a look at the standard library, as it is used in the "real world".

Comment: You can find real life examples in the C++ standard library and many of the boost libraries.

Comment: thanks for the comments. In stead of writing your own library, is there any other scenario where enable_if should be used?

Comment: You might get something from [the introduction of boost::hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introduction). In my opinion, meta-programming likes creating (type-safe) mods for c++...

Comment: `enable_if` shows up in library/template code. In straightforward application code, you typically know whether a function is needed.